# Automate the Manual Work as shown in the image input from excel to website and output the result back yo excel

Tags: javascript, web-scraping

I need to automate this, I have the excel sheet with the data in column A, Row 1, i would like to take the text from row1 put it into link "https://www.lacourt.org/casesummary/ui/index.aspx" in the case number search box and get the result of this back to excel sheet next to column 1

[image]

I am trying to get the status of the resulted search into the excel sheet next to column 1

[image]

please let me know if it is possible as i have tried every possible way with cheerio and scrap.js

Comment: if you're familiar with Python, I know a way to do it. But I'm not familiar with cheerio or scrap.js

Comment: it will be great if you can help me with this i have basic understanding of python. i tried using this with python

import requests
import csv
from selenium import webdriver
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup

Comment: Ok. Not near a computer at the moment, but will be later. I’ll post my solution ASAP.

Answer (score 0):

Hopefully this can get you going. It’s not perfect, as there’s stuff I’d want to clean up, make more efficient, but just wanted to get something to you since you’ve been trying for a few weeks.

You'll have to make some changes too, as I have no idea what your excel sheet contains. Also I have it as a csv file. If it's an excel file, I'll need to change a few things (minor changes). Just let me know, as I didn’t realize you said excel and not csv until I stepped away.

```
from selenium import webdriver
import bs4
import pandas as pd

url = "https://www.lacourt.org/casesummary/ui/index.aspx"

# the 2 lines below will read in your csv file and create a list from your column A. 
# You'll have to specifiy path and filename. And If it's a different column name, change that below too
# remove hash symbol on next two lines

#df = pd.read_csv('path/file.csv')
#case_numbers = df['column A'].tolist()

# I used this 1 element list to test. Just delete this line once you have the above 2 lines sorted out
case_numbers = ['16V00010']



results = pd.DataFrame()
for case_num in case_numbers:
    driver = webdriver.Chrome()
    driver.get(url)

    driver.find_element_by_name("CaseNumber").send_keys(case_num)
    driver.find_element_by_css_selector("input[type='submit'][value='SEARCH']").click()

    html = driver.page_source

    soup = bs4.BeautifulSoup(html,'html.parser')
    status = soup.find('b', string='Status:').parent.next_sibling

    temp_df = pd.DataFrame([[case_num, status]], columns = ['case_number','status'])
    results = results.append(temp_df).reset_index(drop = True)

    driver.close()

print (results)

# saves the results. I don't know what else is in your csv file, so you may need to alter the code a bit
# remove hash below
#results.to_csv('path/new_file.csv', index=False))
```

**Output:**

```
print (results)
  case_number            status
0    16V00010  Legacy Dismissal
```